# How do I select edges that have same value of attributes

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin

Here is an example graph

```
gremlin> v1 = graph.addVertex(id, 1, label,"cell_1")
gremlin> v2 = graph.addVertex(id, 2, label,"cell_2")
gremlin> v1.addEdge("test",v2,id,3,"srving_rsrp",20,"nbr_rsrp",30)
gremlin> v1.addEdge("test",v2,id,4,"srving_rsrp",30,"nbr_rsrp",30)
gremlin> v1.addEdge("test",v2,id,5,"srving_rsrp",10,"nbr_rsrp",40)
```

I need to get the edge where "srving_rsrp" and "nbr_rsrp"are of equal value. I am not able to find a good example that is fitting it

This is where I have reached; Instead of each I would like to have used a filter to create a graph with only edges that match the criteria. I am using Germlin shell which comes with Titan (1.0.0-hadoop)

```
g.V(1).outE('test').each{  it.property('srving_rsrp').value == it.property('nbr_rsrp').value}
```

I am able to do this easily with NetworK in Python; Here is the code for that, which I want to achieve using Germlin

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()  # Create a network Graph

G.add_edge(2,3, time=10,srvingcell=20,neighbourcell=50)
G.add_edge(2,3, time=20,srvingcell=30,neighbourcell=30)
G.add_edge(2,3, time=30,srvingcell=28,neighbourcell=40)
G.add_edge(2,3, time=5,srvingcell=27,neighbourcell=85)
G.edges(data=True)

cutoff = 25

SG=nx.Graph( [ (u,v,d) for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True) if d['srvingcell'] == d['neighbourcell']] )

SG.edges(data=True)

nx.write_gml(SG, "test.gml")
```

Comment: Are you interested in finding any edges with matching properties graph wide, or only those edges with a common vertex and matching properties?

Comment: Basically I want to filter off edges that don't match the rule / match the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer would be to just change your `each` to `filter`:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).outE('test').filter{  it.get().property('srving_rsrp').value == it.get().property('nbr_rsrp').value}
==>e[4][1-test->2]
```

but that uses a lambda and it best to avoid those if possible. I'm not sure if the following will work with Gremlin 3.0.x (which is what Titan 1.0.0 is based on), but you could get rid of the labmda with this:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).outE('test').as('x','y').
                filter(select('x','y').
                         by('srving_rsrp').by('nbr_rsrp').
                       where('x',eq('y')))
==>e[4][1-test->2]
```

You basically provide two labels "x" and "y" to the edges and then apply a filter. In the filter, you select the "x" and "y" labels and for "x" you grab the "srving_rsrp" property value and for the "y" you grab the "nbr_rsrp" property value and filter those where they are `eq` (equal).

This is an example of the [Traversal Induced Values](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#traversal-induced-values) pattern which is discussed in TinkerPop's Recipes.

UPDATE: Traversal Induced Values are even nicer in 3.2.3 (not yet released as of this writing):

```
gremlin> g.V(1).outE('test').as('x','y').
                where('x',eq('y')).
                  by('srving_rsrp').by('nbr_rsrp')
==>e[4][1-test->2]
```

no more nasty `select()`.

Answer (score 0):

While working with Scala , spend some time to get the syntax of the above statements in Groovy right;

Here is it as an example for others

```
val v0 = graph + "cell_1"
val v2 = graph + "cell_2"
val v3 = graph + "cell_3"

val srving_rsrp = Key[Int]("srving_rsrp")
val nbr_rsrp = Key[Int]("nbr_rsrp")

//v0.addEdge("test",v2,T.id,3,"srving_rsrp",20,"nbr_rsrp",30)
//v0.addEdge("test",v2,T.id,4,"srving_rsrp",30,"nbr_rsrp",30)
//v0.addEdge("test",v2,T.id,5,"srving_rsrp",10,"nbr_rsrp",40)

// create edge with typed properties
v0 ---("test", srving_rsrp → 20, nbr_rsrp → 30) --> v2
v0 ---("test", srving_rsrp → 30, nbr_rsrp → 30) --> v2
v0 ---("test", srving_rsrp → 10, nbr_rsrp → 40) --> v2

//v2.addEdge("test",v3,T.id,6,"srving_rsrp",40,"nbr_rsrp",40)
//v2.addEdge("test",v3,T.id,7,"srving_rsrp",15,"nbr_rsrp",45)

v2 ---("test", srving_rsrp → 40, nbr_rsrp → 40) --> v3
v2 ---("test", srving_rsrp → 15, nbr_rsrp → 45) --> v3

//v3.addEdge("test",v2,T.id,8,"srving_rsrp",15,"nbr_rsrp",15)

v3 ---("test", srving_rsrp → 15, nbr_rsrp → 15) --> v2

val g = graph.traversal()
println(v0.outE("test").value(nbr_rsrp).head)
val r = graph.V.outE.filter { it: Edge =>
  (it.property(nbr_rsrp).value() == it.property(srving_rsrp).value())
}
println("value= " + r.count().head()) --> result is 3
```